# How should I efficiently delete alot of records from a mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb

I am using Mongo to store multi tenant data. As part of data cleanup for a tenant I want to delete everything related to the tenant. The tenantId is indexed but there are alot of rows and it takes a long time to query and I have no easy way to get the progress.

Currently I do something

```
db.records.deleteMany({tenantId: x})
```

Is there a better way?

Thinking of doing in batches but like query for x records then build a list of ids to delete. Seems very manual but isit the recommended way?

Comment: I just want to confirm that, you want to delete records from the same model or different models.

Comment: Good question, well done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance may depend on variety of different factors. But here are some options you can try to improve the performance

## Bulk operations

Bulk operations might help here. `bulk.find(query).remove()` is a version of `db.collection.remove(query)` that optimized for large numbers of operations. You can read more about it [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.remove/#bulk-find-remove)

You can use the following way:

Declare a search query:

```
var query= {tenantId: x};
```

Initialize and use a bulk:

```
var bulk = db.yourCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
bulk.find(query).remove() // or try delete() instead of remove()
bulk.execute()
```

The idea here rather not to speed up the removal, but to produce less load.

---

Also you could try [bulkWrite()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

```
db.yourCollection.bulkWrite([
   { deleteMany: {
      "filter" : query,
   }}
])
```

## TTL indexes

It may be not suitable for your use case, but there's entirely another approach without removing by yourself at all.

If it is suitable for you to delete data based on a timestamp, then a [TTL index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) might help you. The idea here is that the record is being removed when the TTL expires.

> Implemented as a special index type, TTL collections make it possible
> to store data in MongoDB and have the mongod automatically remove data
> after a specified period of time.

Comment: I read about the bulk operation method, I always thought its more useful if theres multiple operations. But it sounds like even if theres just 1 delete/remove its faster? 

I think I can consider TTL indexes here. Maybe just need to figure if the time to update is faster

Comment: @JiewMeng From my experience it's not faster, but efficient in terms of cpu load,when dealing with huge amount of data. Also, you could try to use bulk to wrap batch-remove operations,I mean, remove batches in bulk,which is supposed to be also efficient and maybe even faster in some cases. However,it really depends, a variety of factors can affect performance, as I said, it's from my own experience, couldn't find any convincing and unambiguous proofs from the official docs.You can try out those options and find out what approach works better in your case.If TTL is suitbale, it's your safe bet.

Answer (score 1):

Some options that I can think of.

1. Drop the index, before deleting. You can recreate the index after the deletion.
2. Change the [write concern](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/write-concern/) to a lower value, possibly 0. Request won't wait for acknowledgement from secondaries.

   `db.records.deleteMany({tenantId: x},{w : 0});`
3. If there is another field with enough [cardinality](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/glossary/#std-term-cardinality) to reduce the number of documents, try including that in the query.

   Ex: if `anotherField` as 0,1,2,3 as values, then execute the delete command 4 times, each time with different value.

   ```
   db.records.deleteMany({tenantId: x, anotherField: 0},{w : 0});
   db.records.deleteMany({tenantId: x, anotherField: 1},{w : 0});
   db.records.deleteMany({tenantId: x, anotherField: 2},{w : 0});
   db.records.deleteMany({tenantId: x, anotherField: 3},{w : 0});
   ```

Answer (score -1):

[DeleteMany](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/) I think, There must be something common between all the rows that you want to remove from the collection.

You can find out something and then create a query accordingly.

this will help you to remove those records fast.

Let me give you one example. I want to remove all the records where username is not exists.

```
db.collection.deleteMany({ username: {$exists: false} })
```

Answer (score -1):

The best place to start is to find something that all records have in common in-order to removed them all at once.
For example the following code deletes all entries that don't contain an email address.

```
db.users.deleteMany({ email: { $exists: false } })
```

MongoDB documentation have great examples. Link provided below.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/#delete-multiple-documents

You might also want to consider dropping the index since it could be recreated after your done with the operation.

Finally you might want to lower the write concern in your operation in order to speed things up. A compile list of options can be found here
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/write-concern/#w-option

I found a good tutorial on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongodb-delete-multiple-documents-using-mongoshell/ that might help you further.

apologies for any grammatical mistakes since English is not my native tongue

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest two solutions, and also please export your model If anything goes wrong you will have a backup of your data or try this in your test DB first

1. you can use your tenantId as a condition, not matching _id but with extra logic, like if any of the records do have the tenantId delete them so this way all of your tenant data will be removed using a single query.

   ```
   db.records.deleteMany({tenantId : {$exists: true})
   // suggestion- if any of your tenant data has a field tenantId but it is null you can check for a null value also to delete those records.
   ```

2) find command data in all of the records, if there is use it as a condition to delete those records.
for example, all of your tenant data have a common field called type with the same value use delete statement like

```
   db.records.deleteMany({type : 1})
```